# persisting data members with private accessibility

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, datacontract, isolatedstorage, securityexception

I am developing an application in windows phone 7 .I want to persist my object which contains private data members so as to restore my application after tomb stoning. Now the problem  is

```
namespace xyz 
{
          [DataContract]
          public class ClassABC
          {

            [DataMember]
            private string a;

            [DataMember]
            private A b ; // A is a user defined class which is also serializable
          }
 }
```

now when I use

```
  ClassABC abc = new ClassABC();
  var axds= IsolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings;
  axdes["some key"] = abc ;
  IsolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings.save();
```

// this raised a security exception that                                           ClassABC is not serializable because it is not public.

I don't know why is this problem occurring.

Please help.

Comment: I have a class which has got data members which are internal to the class.Now I donnot want them to be made public

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989532/type-is-not-serializable-because-its-not-public

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with my app. Unfortunately WP7 cannot serialize non-public members due to the trust level. To get this to work I had to change my properties all to public and then my serialize/deserialize methods worked like a charm. I wish i had a better work around for someone who NEEDS to keep their properties private but I'm not aware of anything.